# MSSQL create table CHECK for sub-query

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, triggers, check-constraint

I guess no sub-queries are allowed in "CREATE TABLE CHECK" (only current values allowed). But I would like to check the table for condition outer the current row like below:

Pseudocode:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
LoginName varchar(128) NOT NULL CHECK (OLNY ONE of following can be duplicate to an existing record: LoginName, LastName or FirstName. Other two may not),
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255)
)
```

I would like to check this condition: **CHECK (OLNY ONE of following can be duplicate to an existing record: LoginName, LastName or FirstName. Other two may not)**

How to do that? (Please write the code, not only a hint. Thanx)

**SAMPLE DATA**

Existing:

- Jannie, Smith, Jane, Elm Str.
- Johnie, Smith, John, Elm Str.
- Alvaro, Jimenez, Alvaro, 5th Av.

Allowed insert/update:

- Greenhorn, Prochazka, Martin, MyStreet#1
- **Johnie**, Robot, No5, Army Str.
- GodLike, **Smith**, No5, Army Str.

Not allowed:

- **Johnie, Smith, John**, Route 66
- **Alvaro**, Roman, **Alvaro**, Down Str.
- **Alvaro**, Roman, **John**, Down Str.

**To easiest understanding what is not allowed: If one of "name" values is duplicate, rest must be unique**

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? To my knowledge only Firebird allows sub-queries in check constraints.

Comment: I guess the `LoginName` needs to be unique?

Comment: Ah, yes. I haven't written that, because of the pseudocode. But it is just an example. The loginname is not the real problem. The problem is how to use a subquery for checking.

Comment: I have updated the pseudo code...let's check it

Comment: How is this requirement different from just applying a `UNIQUE` constraint across all four columns?

Comment: I have updated the condition, please check

Comment: I think this question would be a lot clearer if you gave an example (say 3-5 rows of existing sample data) and then some examples of new rows that *should* be allowed and rows that *shouldn't* be allowed. I'm still not clear from your narrative, so some examples would probably be easier to reason about.

Comment: ok, I will edit in a moment

Comment: samples added, i hope w/o any mistake